# Remove last node c++ (recursion): double free or corruption (fasttop)

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I am trying to remove the last node in my single linked list and I keep running up against an error:
double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000024e9c20

```
void removeLast (node *& head) {
    if(head == NULL)
        return;
    if(head->next == NULL) {
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        return;
    }
    removeLast(head->next);
}
```

Comment: Did you run your code with `valgrind` or build with address sanitizer enabled?  There's not enough here for us to give much advice, so please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You have chosen not to show us some of your code, and the problem is in that code.

Comment: how do you create a new node?

Comment: @DipStax
```class node
{
    public:
        int data;
        node * next;
};

void create (node * & head);```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using (node *&head) in your function try using (node **head). And the place where you call this function send the parameter as &head.
For eg.

```
int main()
{
     ...
     removelast(&head);
     ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to do use (node *&head) and removelast(head)
I can't use (node **head) and  removelast(&head)